# Jekyll serve on Mac - slow loading

Tags: macos, localhost, jekyll

when I try to run Jekyll (`C(base) cXXX-macpro:website cXXX$ jekyll serve`) on my MAC via the terminal, I receive the following output:

```
Configuration file: /xxx/website/_config.yml
            Source: /xxx/website
       Destination: /xxx/website/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
         AutoPages: Disabled/Not configured in site.config.
        Pagination: Complete, processed 1 pagination page(s)
                    done in 3.629 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/xxx/website'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Then, when I try to load the Website via the Browser, it takes up to 2-3 minutes (sic!) to load the site. Finally, when the site is loaded and I try to click on the links on this site, it takes again 2-3 minutes to load the respective page.

Can anyone tell me why this is the case and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, after two weeks of searching for a solution and posting this question yesterday.

I found the solution here: [Page loading suddenly super slow #372](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/discussions/372).

There seems to be a problem with `https://gitcdn.xyz/...` in the file `head.html` in the `_include` folder. Just change the URL to `https://gitcdn.link/` and it works!